# Dividing up input txt wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm trying to write a program that inputs two txt files as stated by the user, takes the keywords file and splits it into words and values and then takes the tweets file, splits it into a location and a tweet/time.

Example of keywords file (single spaced .txt file):

*love,10

like,5

best,10

hate,1

lol,10

better,10*

Example of tweets file (note this shows only four, there are actually several hundred lines in the actual .txt file):

[41.298669629999999, -81.915329330000006] 6 2011-08-28 19:02:36 Work needs to fly by ... I'm so excited to see Spy Kids 4 with then love of my life ... ARREIC

[33.702900329999999, -117.95095704000001] 6 2011-08-28 19:03:13 Today is going to be the greatest day of my life. Hired to take pictures at my best friend's gparents 50th anniversary. 60 old people. Woo.

[38.809954939999997, -77.125144050000003] 6 2011-08-28 19:07:05 I just put my life in like 5 suitcases

[27.994195699999999, -82.569434900000005] 6 2011-08-28 19:08:02 @Miss_mariiix3 is the love of my life

So far my program looks like:

```
#prompt the user for the file name of keywords file
keywordsinputfile = input("Please input file name: ")
tweetsinputfile = input ("Please input tweets file name: ")

#try to open given input file
try:
    k=open(keywordsinputfile, "r")
except IOError:
    print ("{} file not found".format(keywordsinputfile))
try:
    t=open(tweetsinputfile, "r")
except IOError:
    print ("{} file not found".format(tweetsinputfile))
    exit()

def main ():   #main function
    kinputfile = open(keywordsinputfile, "r")         #Opens File for keywords
    tinputfile = open(tweetsinputfile, "r")           #Opens file for tweets
    HappyWords = {}
    HappyValues = {}
    for line in kinputfile:                           #splits keywords
        entries = line.split(",")
        hvwords = str(entries[0])
        hvalues = int(entries[1])
        HappyWords["keywords"] = hvwords           #stores Happiness keywords
        HappyValues["values"] = hvalues            #stores Happiness Values
    for line in tinputfile:
        twoparts = line.split("]")  #splits tweet file by ] creating a location and tweet parts, tweets are ignored for now
        startlocation = (twoparts[0])   #takes the first part (the locations)
    def testing(startlocation):
        for line in startlocation:     
            intlocation = line.split("[")      #then gets rid of the "[" at the beginning of the locations
            print (intlocation)
    testing(startlocation)

main()
```

What I am hoping to get out of this is (for an infinite number of lines, the actual file contains way more than the four shown above)

```
41.298669629999999, -81.915329330000006
33.702900329999999, -117.95095704000001
38.809954939999997, -77.125144050000003
27.994195699999999, -82.569434900000005
```

And what I am getting is:

```
['', '']
['2']
['7']
['.']
['9']
['9']
['4']
['1']
['9']
['5']
['6']
['9']
['9']
['9']
['9']
['9']
['9']
['9']
['9']
[',']
[' ']
['-']
['8']
['2']
['.']
['5']
['6']
['9']
['4']
['3']
['4']
['9']
['0']
['0']
['0']
['0']
['0']
['0']
['0']
['5']
```

So in other words it's only processing the final line of the txt file and splitting it up individually as well.

After this I have to store them in such a way that I can split them again into the first part in one list and the second part in another list
(example:

```
for line in locations:
    entries = line.split(",")
    latitude = intr(entries[0])
    longitude = int(entries[1])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are overwriting  `HappyWords["keywords"] ` and `HappyValues["values"]` in the loop again and again. So you are seeing only the last line from keywords file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I fixed that, but the part of the code I am trying to extract doesn't use those values at all. Still have the same error.

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in all variables - this way you can find where you make mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to stick in some tracing **print** statements to show what's going on.  I did it this way:

```
for line in tinputfile:
    twoparts = line.split("]")  #splits tweet file by ] creating a location and tweet parts, tweets are ignored for now
    startlocation = (twoparts[0])   #takes the first part (the locations)
    print ("-----------")
    print ("twoparts", twoparts) 
    print ("startlocation", startlocation)
def testing(startlocation):
    for line in startlocation:     
        print ("line", line)
        intlocation = line.split("[")      #then gets rid of the "[" at the beginning of the locations
        print ("intlocation", intlocation)
testing(startlocation)
```

... and got a trace beginning with:

```
-----------
twoparts ['[41.298669629999999, -81.915329330000006', " 6 2011-08-28 19:02:36 Work needs to fly by ... I'm so excited to see Spy Kids 4 with then love of my life ... ARREIC\n"]
startlocation [41.298669629999999, -81.915329330000006
-----------
twoparts ['[33.702900329999999, -117.95095704000001', " 6 2011-08-28 19:03:13 Today is going to be the greatest day of my life. Hired to take pictures at my best friend's gparents 50th anniversary. 60 old people. Woo.\n"]
startlocation [33.702900329999999, -117.95095704000001
-----------
twoparts ['[38.809954939999997, -77.125144050000003', ' 6 2011-08-28 19:07:05 I just put my life in like 5 suitcases\n']
startlocation [38.809954939999997, -77.125144050000003
-----------
twoparts ['[27.994195699999999, -82.569434900000005', ' 6 2011-08-28 19:08:02 @Miss_mariiix3 is the love of my life\n']
startlocation [27.994195699999999, -82.569434900000005
line [
intlocation ['', '']
line 2
intlocation ['2']
line 7
```

**Analysis:**

There are two basic problems:

1. Your processing statement, **testing(startlocation)**, is outside the loop, so it uses only the last input line.
2. As you can see in the output of "twoparts", your desired coordinates are still in *string* format, not a list of floats.  You need to strip off the brackets and split them apart.  *Then* convert them to float.  In the current form, when you iterate through **intlocation**, you iterate through the characters of a string, not through two floats.

Also: Why do you define a function inside a loop?  This redefines the function on every execution.  Move it before the main program; this is where well-behaved functions hang out.  :-)

---

**Added information on point 2:**

Let's step through your code, using the last line of sample input.
Start at the top of the loop **for line in tinputfile**

```
twoparts = line.split("]")
```

**twoparts** is now a pair of elements, both strings:

```
['[27.994195699999999, -82.569434900000005',
 ' 6 2011-08-28 19:08:02 @Miss_mariiix3 is the love of my life\n']
```

You then set **startlocation** to the first element:

```
'[27.994195699999999, -82.569434900000005'
```

Then comes the redundant re-definition of function **testing**, which produces no change.  The next statement calls **testing**; we enter the routine.

```
testing(startlocation)
for line in startlocation:
```

The important part here is that **startlocation** is a *string*:

```
'[27.994195699999999, -82.569434900000005'
```

... so when you execute that loop, you iterate through the string, one character at a time.

**Correction:**

To be honest, I don't know what **testing** is supposed to do.
It looks like all you need to do is strip off that leading bracket:

```
intlocation = startlocation.split('[')
```

... or simply

```
intlocation = startlocation[1:]
```

Instead, if you want the *float* values as a two-element list, (a) knock off the bracket as above, split the elements at the comma, and convert to float:

```
intlocation = [ float(x) for x in startlocation[1:].split(',') ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the input and excellent analysis. I've been learning Python for about two months now and I have to say this is the most complicated thing I've had to do. Could you further explain your second point? 

Unfortunately I learn best through analyzing what worked, and I've never had to deal with txt inputs this complicated before.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like much of what this really needs is `ast.literal_eval`.

```
for line in tinputfile:
    twoparts = line.split("]")
    startlocation = ast.literal_eval(twoparts[0] + ']') # add the ']' back in
    # startlocation is now a list of two coordinates.
```

But you might be better off still using `re`.

```
> import re
> example = '[27.994195699999999, -82.569434900000005] 6 2011-08-28 19:02:36 text text text text'
> fmt = re.split(r'\[(-?[0-9.]+),\s?(-?[0-9.]+).\s*\d\s*(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})',example)
> fmt
['', '27.994195699999999', '-82.569434900000005', '2011-08-28 19:02:36', ' text text text text']
> location = (float(fmt[1]), float(fmt[2]))
> time = fmt[3]
> text = fmt[4]
```

So, what's going on?

Each of those `(...)` in the regular expression (the `re` module), tells `re.split` "Make this piece its own index".

The first and second are `-?[0-9.]`. That means match anything which may have a minus sign followed by numbers and decimal place (we could be stricter, but you don't really need to).

The next set of `()` match any date: `\d{4}` means "four digits". `\d{1,2}` means "one or two digits".

Or, you could use both together:

```
> fmt = re.split(r'\[(-?[0-9.]+,\s?-?[0-9.]+).\s*\d\s*(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})',example)
> fmt # watch what happens when I change the grouping.
['', '27.994195699999999, -82.569434900000005', '2011-08-28 19:02:36', ' text text text text']
> location = literal_eval('(' + fmt[1] + ')')
> time = fmt[2]
> text = fmt[3]
```